# How to pass data across two threads without blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost, concurrency

I have two threads: a writer thread, and a reader thread. The writer thread runs in a periodic loop (I used Boost's `boost::asio::steady_timer` and `boost::asio::io_context` to create the periodic loop). On each period, the writer generates new `data` that is available for reading. The reader thread may or may not run periodically. Every time the reader thread runs, it wants to read the latest available `data` from the writer thread. It doesn't need to read all the `data` ever generated by the writer thread, only the latest one.

I thought about using a mutex from `boost::mutex` to lock the `data` to allow the two threads to concurrently access the `data`. However, if the reader takes too long to read the `data`, then the writer thread might block too long on the mutex, and violate its loop period time.

Is there a way to allow the writer thread to always be able to write into a shared buffer, replacing any old `data` with the most recent, regardless if the reader actually reads; while also allowing the reader thread to always read the most recent `data` from the buffer?

Comment: What is `data`?  A fundamental type? A small class? A large class?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for "read-copy-update".

Comment: `data` is a struct with many fields, so reading it is not atomic

Comment: The producer can create new instances for each data and write a pointer to some shared location atomically indicating where to fetch the latest. To deal with memory deallocation, smart pointers can be used since the consumer might not get its hands on every single instance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock

Comment: https://github.com/rigtorp/Seqlock  Shows a possible implementation.